Java application running in ECS Fargate Service cannot load credentials
I have an ECS service which is running on Fargate (latest version). The service runs a Java (Spring) application which makes use of the AWS SDK (version 2.29.29). However, the following error is occurring when making AWS API calls:
Unable to load credentials from any of the providers in the chain AwsCredentialsProviderChain(credentialsProviders=[
    EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(), 
    SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider(), 
    ProfileCredentialsProvider(profileName=default, profileFile=ProfileFile(sections=[])), 
    InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider()
]) : [
    EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(): Unable to load credentials from system settings. Access key must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) or system property (aws.accessKeyId).,

    SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider(): Unable to load credentials from system settings. Access key must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) or system property (aws.accessKeyId).,

    ProfileCredentialsProvider(profileName=default, profileFile=ProfileFile(sections=[])): Profile file contained no credentials for profile 'default': ProfileFile(sections=[]),

    InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(): Failed to load credentials from IMDS.
]

My task is configured to use a Task Role, which looks like this:
{
    // ...
    "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
                },
                "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
            }
        ]
    }
}

The role also has numerous policies to allow access to various AWS services. I've confirmed that, while "SSH'd" into the container, I can execute AWS API calls via the CLI -- for example, I can list the contents of a bucket which is described by one of the policies on the role. So thinks appear to be "correct" in this regard.
When I connect to the service (via ecs execute-command), here's what I see:

aws sts get-caller-identity gives a valid response.
curl 169.254.170.2/v2/metadata returns metadata correctly.
curl 169.254.170.2${AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI} returns an access key id, secret access key, and token.

In the error above, I'd expect the InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider to be the provider which ends up "finding credentials". But I'm not sure how to resolve the error message: Failed to load credentials from IMDS.

Are you using a fairly recent version of the AWS SDK in your application?

Yes, we're using 2.29.29.

How do you have the SDK configured? I think you need to have the ContainerCredentialProvider enabled https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/auth/credentials/ContainerCredentialsProvider.html I've never had to do anything to enable that though, it's usually enabled by default if you haven't changed any of the default AWS SDK settings.

Would it possible to share your java pom.xml or gradle file?. In v1 of JDK one of the root cause we had was to explicitly add dependency on aws-java-sdk-sts library too. Since you are using V2, not sure if we need to apply the same. Also, if you can share on how you are initializing the AWS Client, it will be good.
